# Is there any idiom that means "go ahead with something"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there any idiom that means "go ahead with something"? I thought about "giving oneself the green light", "get a jump on something", but the first one is contrived and the second one means something partially different from "go ahead with something". Can you think of a good replacement for that idiom?

> I wanted to go ahead with the idea of getting myself a breast implant.
>
> I will weigh the benefits and consequences before going ahead with the
>   idea of getting a nose surgery.

Comment: By "with the idea of..." do you mean exploring what's *involved* with the surgery, or proceeding with the *actual* surgery?

Comment: proceeding with the actual surgery

Comment: Idiomatically, ***press on** [with something]*. It's usually pointless verbiage to refer to ***the idea of** [thing]* rather than just ***thing***, especially in a context where even ***getting myself*** is effectively optional / redundant "padding".

Comment: Perhaps "I am going to have the breast implant." Or "I am going to proceed with the operation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[swing into action](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/swing+into+action)

> To begin some activity with great enthusiasm, intensity, and speed.